# Linq to list, then to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, linq, list, datagrid

I have an `Account(accountID, accountName, transactionCount)` and I want, using LINQ insert all rows into `List` and display that list on `DataGrid`.

I load rows into `List`:

```
List<Account> accounts = dataContext.Accounts.ToList();
```

Now I don't know how to insert that into `DataGrid`, I predefined `DataGrid` columns. I can imagine that I'm missing some maping.

Also, maybe I can directly load all table rows into `DataGrid` (but with predefined columns). But I think that I will need this `List` option for joining tables.

Here is the XAML code of DataGrid. I tried to use Gamesh tip, but grid remains blank:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,25,0,0" Name="dataGridAccounts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account ID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transactions Count" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Assign accounts list to ItemsSource of DataGrid. like datagrid.ItemsSource=accounts;

Comment: I tried it, data don't appear on DataGrid. Cells remain blank. I store 4 records in table and 4 blank rows appeared in DataGrid.

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: But there is no more code, just that line: `dataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = accounts;`

Maybe I set something wrong with DataGrid, but I didn't change anything, except adding column headers.

Comment: XAML code would help

Comment: I updated my main post with XAML code. Chat option appeared, but I can't chat because of reputation.

Comment: You need to add binding refer the below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the add binding as below.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,25,0,0" Name="dataGridAccounts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account ID" Binding="{Binding accountID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Name" Binding="{Binding accountName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transactions Count" Binding="{Binding transactionCount}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```